# Conditional formatting on Excel for a range of numbers

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I use the conditional formatting to change the cell color to red if the number was out of this range (55-83), my problem is that I don't want the cell to stay red until I fill it with the correct number , I want the cell to stay clear until I fill it with the wrong number.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following formula in your conditional format:

```
=AND(CELL<>"",OR(CELL<55,CELL>83))
```

[image: Conditional Formatting Rule]